Adding delay to live-stream video using C++ or Python
im making a project main idea of which is to create a real-time Motion Extraction tool.
Right now im not stage where i can't find solution to one problem: to make visual motion extraction effect from video you need to: take video > dublicate it > inverse dublicated version > lower transparency at 50% to inversed video  > add delay to the video.
I achieved every step EXCEPT delaying real-time stream.
Right now i have no clue how can i add artificial delay to stream and wanted to ask if there any c++ or at least python library which allow to add artificial and non the less important consistent "lag" which i can control?
(because increasing or decreasing delay time making more sudden movement more visible and vice-versa, consider it as changing exposure time on cameras).

Check already available open source software written in C++ - OBS. Way more optimal than looking for a library
